# HTML with draggable elements to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, coldfusion

I have a report builder that when served up has several div elements with charts and graphs. Now the user can dragged and sorted these elements how they wish. My issue now is how to capture the html page so the PDF will reflect this new layout. 
Before I was capturing the html page in Coldfusions cfsavecontent and sending that to a process page to create the pdf. This does not work when elements have been dragged and sorted dynamically. Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.

```
<form name="fform" action="process.cfm" method="post" target="iprocess">
    <cfsavecontent variable="strPDF">
        <div id='graph1'>            
            <div style='position:absolute; top:500px; left:175px'>
             <span>Report Data Here</span>
            </div>        
        </div>

        <div id='graph2'>            
            <div style='position:absolute; top:500px; left:175px'>
             <span>Report Data Here</span>
            </div>        
        </div>

        <div id='graph3'>            
            <div style='position:absolute; top:575px; left:175px'>
             <span>Report Data Here</span>
            </div>        
        </div>

    </cfsavecontent>

    <input type="hidden" name="strPDF" value="#strPDF#">
    <input type="submit" value="Create PDF">


    <div>        
        <div>#strPDF#</div>
    </div>

</form>

<iframe height="300" width="700" src="" name="iprocess"></iframe>
```

JQuery is used to make the elements draggable. Is it possible to recapture the page to pdf with the new element positions?

Comment: Some relevant code snippets would be nice here.

Comment: please come come with some code tried by you, can be read from Google search

Comment: why can't you sent updated sort order  back to server?

Answer (score 2):

Answer = No  (there... that was simple.)

**TL;DR**

Ok let me see if I understand this right.  You have a page with charts and dynamic content that allows user experience customization.

You have **report builder**, you are serving up charts with what? with cfchart? and you were at one time doing a **cfsavecontent** to a variable but you are not doing that now. So what are you doing? Forget it...it doesn't matter.

Let me tell you what I have to do and I think you might want to consider something similar.

I have my page of charts that are **.png** generated serverside via **cfchart**. I do a **cfsavecontent** grabbing the variable and doing a **cfdocument** PDF generation. This will give your people or person something to print and look at. It meets whatever PDF print requirements you might have. The PDF styling no matter how you slice it is limited. you will no doubt have already experienced styling give and take when you look at your generated page of charts and divs, and your PDF output page side by side.

If you want client customizations (dragging things and what not). Then store those as user preferences in a table and when they return you can set things up a certain way and then have that variable handy you can generate a PDF based on that.

Understand that PDF does not follow 'all styling behaviors'. You will need to consider your give and take scenarios. If the user wants to print something like a chart, then my god man...keep it super simple and keep it all native in coldfusion: **cfchart**, **cfsavecontent**, **cfdocument**.

Good luck.

Comment: ColdFusion 11 is supposed to allow for pixel-perfect PDF rendering of HTML. But yes, the user customization would have to be saved and the HTML completely re-rendered for CF 11 to export the changes to PDF.

Comment: I'm on CF10 and it there are styling nuances and I.E. is the standard here so there are even more styling funzies to consider. We haven't jumped to CF11 yet, but either way I don't know what the OP is using (as currently posted by him). I don't want to assume anything outside what I am already assuming. lol. :)